# Altium designer Ignoring Pin mismatch between schematic symbol and footprint while importing the design to PCB

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, altium, schematic

I am trying to import the schematic into the PCB doc in Altium designer and found that it is not showing any error in eco for the mismatch in the pin count  between the schematic symbol and footprint. To elaborate I had mapped a 24 pin SOP footprint for a simple 2 pin header schematic symbol and Altium was able to import the SOIC into the board without any warning on the pin count mismatch, which I believe should not be case with other CAD tools. Please do help me with the issue and let me know if there is any way to fix this.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I think this question is best answered on the Altium forum and / or through Altium technical support ...

Answer (score 0):

Altium (or other PCB CAD programs) won't complain about unused pins in a PCB footprint because it is quite common to have some unused pins.

The PCB program will be happy as long as the pin numbers from the schematic part can be found in the associated footprint.

Comment: Hi Peter, thanks for the answer but, here I am not saying about the unused pins., what actually my concern is Altium is not giving any error when I map a 20 pin connector footprint to a schematic symbol with only 2 pins. Ideally the pin count of the schematic symbol and footprint should match to get the netlist generated and importrd into the board